# Mask a View with the alpha from another view in Swift

Tags: swift, mask

I've been struggling for a view hours to figure out how to get my view masked by a shape that is in another view. Basically I have a circular countdown timer that I want to be masked out by an animating circle that scales up from the center of the timer when the timer is reset.

I tried setting `timerMask.maskView = timerCircleGrahics` where `timerCircleGraphics` is the name of my timer animation view. But this is giving me very strange results when I test the app. It seems to clip the view to the rectangle bounds of my mask view rather than the alpha of the bounds that are drawn within that view. The mask layer is centered and being drawn properly, but I've never attempted this before so am not sure if I am doing it right.

Here is the class for my mask shape:

```
class timerBackgroundMask: UIView {
    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
        var ovalPath = UIBezierPath(ovalInRect: CGRectMake(0, 0, 238, 238))
        colorGreen.setFill()
        ovalPath.fill()
    }
}
```

Then using IB, I assign this mask to a manually placed View in my Storyboard called `timerMask`. I am realizeing now that by assigning `timerBackgroundMask` class to `timerMask` I have programatically added a subview to my manually placed Storyboard view, but I feel like the alpha should come through just the same when set this view to mask out anotherview. Here is the code i use to set the mask

```
timerCircleGraphics.layer.mask = timerMask.layer
```

The result I am getting is pretty weird:

[image]

The red portion should be a circle that is partially clipped by my `timerMask` from the center outward. The light green circle that you see is simply the background view of the counter, however it happens to be the exact position and size as my `timerBackgroundMask` for reference.

Comment: Can you share your mask shape code?

Comment: Code and image added as requested

Answer (score 1):

Don't bother creating a class and using the Storyboard. Do it straight in code, the simple way:

```
var ovalPath = UIBezierPath(ovalInRect: CGRectMake(0, 0, 238, 238))
colorGreen.setFill()
ovalPath.fill()
var mask = CAShapeLayer()
mask.path = ovalPath.CGPath
timerCircleGraphics.layer.mask = mask
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm trying to reverse engineer this in Swift as I am new and Swift is my first iOS development language! I don't understand how to write the 4th line.
I tried `var mask = CAShapeLayer` but when i try to set `mask.path` i get the error that `CAShapeLayer has no member named path`.

Comment: Did you import `QuartzCore`? also I apologize for missing the swift issue :) I rewrote the code

Comment: QuartzCore import did the trick, however the mask is allowing my timerCircleGraphics to show through rather than cutting it out, i.e., in photoshop or after effects terms, my mask is set to "add" rather than "subtract". Searching the documentation I am having trouble finding out how to change this parameter.